# Ionic Capacitor Push Notification Test Case

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor, testcase

I'm currently learning how to build a push notification application using Ionic Capacitor and Firebase, was wondering how to mock up or do test cases on the push notification methods.

Currently using these function to get permission but I'm getting confused on how to mock up/create test case for the following.

```
PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
  if (result.receive === 'granted') {
    // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
    PushNotifications.register();
  } else {
    // Show some error
  }
});

// On success, we should be able to receive notifications
PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
  (token: Token) => {
    alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
  }
);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using a using spy on requestPermission and returning a mocked promise with 'granted' - but that's not working.

Comment: Please post that code. It would be a starting point for answering your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask